# processMessage(Chat chat, Message message) not working in Android

Tags: android

I am using aSmack-2010.05.07 XMPP library for writing down chat application on android,

Here is my associated code,

```
chatManager = LoginScreen.getConnection().getChatManager();

 System.out.println("Chat Manager created .......");



    chat = chatManager.createChat(JID,new MessageListener() 
     {
        public void processMessage(Chat arg0, Message message) 
        {
            System.out.println("MSG = "+message.getBody());

            displayReceivedMesage(message.getBody());
        }
    });
```

but displayReceiveMessage()function never gets called, concludes that means the function

processMessage() doesn't hit at all.

Please Help me I am stuck here very badly.

Any help will be appreciable.

Best Regards,

~Anup

Answer (score 0):

you should replace your `System.out.println` with `Log` . System.out.println will not working on Android,

Comment: I think you didnt get my question the problem is not with printing this SOP but the problem is with the callback of MessageListener, I mean to say the callback is not working.

Answer (score -1):

`System.out` will print to `/dev/null` by default so you can't see anything of your printed lines.